# Add New/Custom module in Phabricator

Tags: php, phabricator

I installed the Phabricator using Bitnami stack and try to add new module "statistic about projects and people" having functionalities like: graph of project timeline etc. Please suggest the way how we can implement a feature like this.I did not found any documentation only looked https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabdev/

Answer (score 1):

If this new module is something you've downloaded, you can put the PHP files into the "extensions" subdirectory, or if it is a bigger extension with its own directory heirarchy, keep it separate and `bin/config set load-libraries '["extension_name" => "path/to/extension"]'` (once you have more than one extension, it might be easier to just edit the Phabricator config file and restart the server, as you need to list all the existing extensions in the above command as well).

If you are writing a new extension yourself, then there isn't really any official API documentation as such - the best thing is to find a similar extension, or part of Phabricator core (the applications are all examples of extensions really) and use its source code as an example.  There is some basic documentation: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/